# When are the JSTL XML files actually read?

Tags: java, web-applications, jstl

I read the info about the JSTL tag here:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

And there's one thing I really don't understand...

When you do reference some files like here:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

or here:

```
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
```

When is this file actually read?  Is this file actually read at all from the network?  If that file is actually read from the network, how would development/testing be done in a highly-securized environment where there's no external network access at all (no Internet)?

Can this file (these files) be read once and saved locally and then referenced locally?

If I try to open that webpage or to do a *wget http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core*, I'm getting apparently something that is meant to be read by a human, not by a webapp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the servletcontainer starts up, it scans the entire classpath for any `.tld` files, including the `/META-INF` folder of all deployed JAR files. The JSTL JAR file has among others a `c.tld` file which starts like follows:

```xml
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

  <description>JSTL 1.1 core library</description>
  <display-name>JSTL core</display-name>
  <tlib-version>1.1</tlib-version>
  <short-name>c</short-name>
  <uri>http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core</uri>

  ...
```

Note the `<uri>` entry. This is parsed and remembered during servletcontainer's startup. The `.tld` file declares for every single tag the tag handler class which represent the concrete Java code doing all the work "behind the scenes". For example, the `<c:out>` is declared as follows:

```xml
 <tag>
    <description>
        Like &lt;%= ... &gt;, but for expressions.
    </description> 
    <name>out</name>
    <tag-class>org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.rt.core.OutTag</tag-class>
    <body-content>JSP</body-content>
    ...
```

Now, when a JSP file declares a taglib with exactly this URI, then the `.tld` file in question will be used to locate the tag classes and execute them.

So, the taglib URI is just a virtual address which exist only in the context of the servletcontainer and not outside, even though some taglibs happen to have a real HTTP site behind that URI. The URI is just supposed to be an unique identifier. It doesn't necessarily need to be `http://something`. It can be everything, but a website address is a relatively robust unique identifier. This guarantees almost 100% that no other taglib will have the same URI. You see this uniqueness also back in package names by the way.

Comment: +1 and accepted... *"So, the taglib URI is just a virtual address which exist only in the context of the servletcontainer and not outside"*... Oh wow. And yet it starts with 'http://' :(  I somehow find this more than very highly confusing :-/  I know about package names, but at least these do not start with what looks like a protocol : )

Comment: Note that it's an URI, not an URL. See Wikipedia for the difference.

Comment: oh sure... And that in itself is a **MAJOR** source of confusion amongst people too.  The URI / URL distinction in itself is a major SNAFU'ed concept.  Here we have an URI that looks just like an URL and because an URI can (it doesn't have to, but it can) identify a resource by a location, this is all very, very, very confusing.  I sadly think we live in a very confusing world, made of incomplete, poorly thought, "standards" and "specs".  Thankfully some discipline (like engineering and medicine) have higher standards than computing ; )

Comment: but, just like my question about EL (where you pointed out that nowadays there where better ways to work than jsp/servlet but where all the other posters saw nothing wrong and considered me 'crazy' for wanting to remove some duplication), I expect most people to see "nothing wrong here" and to blindly consider that everything they're getting served is the one true holy non-confusing word from the great languages and APIs gods...